# Overloaded function calling function with same name but different parameters

Tags: c++, function, linked-list, overloading, singly-linked-list

I am creating a linked list. I want to call the function

```
addToTail(head*, data)
```

from the function

```
  addToTail(head*){int n = length(head*);  addtoTail(head*, n)}
```

which contains a function which would calculate the length of the list.

this unfortunately gives me an error which is

```
\linkedList.cpp:97:16: error: too few arguments to function 'void addAtTail(node*, int)'
```

It seems to make perfect sense to me, Am I doing something wrong?

Here is the code. Any comments to improve it otherwise would be appreciated.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node* next;
};

void changeToNull(struct node** head)
{
    *head = NULL;
}

int listLength(struct node* head)
{
    struct node* curr = head;
    int i = 0;
    while(curr!=NULL)
        {
        i++;
        curr = curr->next;
        }
    return i;
}



void addAtTail(struct node* head)
{
    int length = listLength(head);
    addAtTail(head, length);
}

void addAtTail(struct node* head, int n)
{
    struct node* newNode = new node;
    struct node* curr = new node;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    newNode->data = n;
    curr= head;
    while(curr->next!=NULL)
    {
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    curr->next = newNode;
}

int main()
{
    //changeToNull(&head);
    addAtTail(head);
    printList(head);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
addToTail(head*){int n = length(head*);  addtoTail(head*, n)}
```

Here `head*` is a typename not a fromal argument parameter. You need to do :

```
addToTail(node* head){int n = length(head);  addtoTail(head, n)}
```

---

Note:
You do not have `length(node*)` defination, you defined :

```
listLength(struct node*);
```

So you should use `int n = listLength(head)`

Comment: I do not understand why it is a typename. I thought my typename is "node*" and "head" is the argument.

Comment: then you should write (node* head)